# Google Places get LatLng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geocoding

I am using the Autocomplete method to get Place Suggestions and when I click the Place I want to choose, I want to extract the `Lat` and `Lng` which is placed under `place.geometry.location` as below.

[image: Firebug Screenshot]

As per my observation, the keys `ib` and `jb` keep changing with every session. Is there any way I can extract the `Lat` and `Lng` predictably?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
        zoom : 13,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $('#searchTextField').bind('keydown keypress', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var inputQuery = $('#searchTextField').val();

            if (inputQuery.length >= 2) {
                //console.log(inputQuery);

                /*
                var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

                service.getPlacePredictions({
                    input : inputQuery
                }, callback);
                */

                var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
                var options = {
                    types : ['geocode']
                };

                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

                // Acting on Selecting a place
                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                    //infowindow.close();
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    console.log(place);
                    console.log(place.formatted_address);
                    console.log(place.name);
                    console.log(place.geometry.location);
                    console.log(place.geometry.location[0]);

                    // Show the map to the current location selected
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);
                        // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                    }

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position : place.geometry.location,
                        map : map,
                        draggable : true,
                    });

                    $.each(place.geometry.location, function(key, value) {
                        console.log(key + ": " + value);
                    }); 
                });
            }

        }, 0);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`place.geometry.location` is a [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), so you can call its `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods.

```
var location = place.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat();
var lng = location.lng();
```

You'll see that these methods are present in your inspection of this object.

Never use undocumented properties such as the `ib` and `jb` you discovered. Google compiles the Maps API using the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or a similar tool, which generates random names for private properties and variables.

Comment: i'm using places webservice api, how to get lat long from responses ?

Comment: what is the place variable here i am getting an error.

Comment: When use autocomplate class you could have  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();