# split not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

on click of google map i got lat and long.then i try to split it,but it's not working.
when i alert input variable it display lat and long.but when i `alert(latlngStr[0])` nothing is alert.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
var input=e.latLng;alert(input);
var latlngStr = input.split(',',2);alert(latlngStr[0]);
var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
});
```

Comment: What does alert(input) give you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15315483/74585

Comment: your syntax for the split seems fine. however you do not need to use the input.split(',',2). It can be input.split(',');

Comment: Javascript has [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). What is the type of `input`? `alert(typeof input)`

Comment: Exactly. The million dollar question everyone is asking is what does alert(input) give you?

Comment: it gives latitude and longitude.such as `23.0171240, 72.5330533`

Comment: no..like (23.0171240, 72.5330533)

Comment: yes..the code is same..but what happen if the lat and lng is in bracket like `(23.0171240, 72.5330533)`.

Comment: no issues . it would still output (23.0171240

Comment: Teemu, it is a string. cause a marker is an individual spot on the map and hence can have only one latlng

Comment: @MarsOne Looks an [object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) to me...

Comment: `e.latLng` is an object. It has methods like `lat()`, `lng()` to get the lat and lng values. try `input.lat()`

Comment: @MarsOne Yep, I've already removed that comment, wasn't your comment hasty as well?. OP can now choose between `input = e.latLng.toString()` and the methods built in `e.latLng`.

Comment: The built in methods would be a better choice for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking inputs from Shakib's comment your Code should ideally be as follows

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
var input=e.latLng; alert(input);
var lat = input.lat();
var lng = input.lng();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
});
```

Consider using console.log() instead of alert();

Comment: thanks man ..it is worked.but i don't understand the reason behind it.beacause `e.latlong` provide lat and long both,so why it is not split?

Comment: Because it is an object. String.split works on strings. Alert will output anything. Thats why its better to use console.log where you can exactly see the type of variable created is an object, array or string. :)