# Google Maps API Search Box: Using exact lats and longs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to get a Google Map in a browser to go to exact decimal-degree locations by typing them into the search box. I've set up the search box as per the API docs except I removed the biasing toward my current location.

These seems to work reasonably well if the is a 'place' near the coordinates I want, but doesn't do anything if there is nothing there. As my users will typically be searching for rural locations there is often 'nothing there', but I want to go there anyway (e.g., searching 0, 0 should take me to the sea off west Africa). I know I can use 0N, 0E - but some of my users want to use +/- not cardinal compass points (i.e. -90 to +90 and -180 to +180, not N, S, E, W).

Ideally, I don't want a separate control - the Search box is integrated and very nearly does what I want.

Is there any way to force the Search box to go to coordinates regardless? (assuming +ve is N and E, -ve is S and W)

(Bonus points if there is a way to allow it to accept UTM locations as Google Earth does :) )

EDIT:

The code is as per the API docs here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

with this section removed:

```html
// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your code or the link the reference

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide minimal, complete and verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You may also try to check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916221/getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-google-places-search-api-using-javascript